# Data messing up on saved image but perfect on page display

Tags: javascript, html, css

My this code works fine and saves the image onclick in the folder but it shifts the input fields a little bit up and i cannot identify the issue.
Because everything is all right and displayed perfect on the page the problem only comes up on the saved image and also it does not fit the image in print preview.

Where is the problem or where i am doing wrong?

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'traditional_arabicregular';
    src: url('fontsKU/traditional_arabic_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fontsKU/traditional_arabic_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
.arx {
    font-family: 'traditional_arabicregular', Arial, sans-serif;
}
    /* Style for the canvasSaveder div that holds the image and input fields */
  
  .canvasSaveder {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* Use percentage width to make it responsive */
    height: 100%;
    /* Use percentage width to make it responsive */
  }
  /* Style for the image */
  
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  /* Style for the input fields */
  
        input {
            position: absolute;
            border: none;
             font-size: 30px;
             background-color: transparent;
        }
  
  .nameA {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 63%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 3%;
    top: 30%;
  }
  
  .nameE {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 63%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 3%;
    top: 39%;
  }
  
  .nationalityE {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 23%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 25%;
    top: 49.5%;
  }
  
  .nationalityA {
    font-size: 23px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    width: 17%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 49%;
    top: 49.5%;
  }
  
  .department {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 53%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 13%;
    top: 58%;
  }
  
  .title {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 53.5%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 12.5%;
    top: 69%;
  }
  
  .blood {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 9%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 24%;
    top: 78%;
  }
  
  .expiry {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 8%;
    left: 22%;
    top: 88%;
  }
  
  .staffno {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 28%;
    height: 8.5%;
    left: 71%;
    top: 90%;
  }
  
  .photo {
    width: 28%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    /* Change the position to absolute */
    right: 1%;
    /* Adjust the right property to position the image from the right edge */
    top: 40%;
  }
</style>
    
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <button type="button" onclick="printStaffID()">Print Staff ID</button>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black;">

<div id="printThisDiv">
  <div class="canvasSaveder">
    <img src="images/kacid.jpg" alt="Staff ID Image">
    <!-- Position input fields over the image with percentage-based margins -->
    <input dir="rtl" id="charA" type="text" name="aname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($aname); ?>" class="arx resizeME nameA">
    <input id="charE" type="text" name="ename" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ename); ?>" class="resizeME nameE">
    <input id="natE" type="text" name="enationality" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cename); ?>" class="resizeME nationalityE">
    <input id="natA" type="text" name="anationality" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($caname); ?>" class="arx resizeME nationalityA">
    <input id="department" type="text" name="department" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($dename); ?>" class="resizeME department">
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tename); ?>" class="resizeME title">
    <input id="blood" type="text" name="blood" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($blename); ?>" class="resizeME blood">
    <input id="date" type="text" name="expiry" class="resizeME expiry" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($current_date); ?>">
    <input id="staffnos" type="text" name="staffno" class="resizeME staffno" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($staffno); ?>">
    <span id="photo">
      <img src="images/employees/empPhotos/30546.jpg" class="photo">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="saveAndPrintDiv()">Save and Print</button>

<script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>
  function saveAndPrintDiv() {
    var content = document.getElementById("printThisDiv");

    // Use html2canvas to capture the content
    html2canvas(content, {
      scrollX: 0,
      scrollY: 0,
    }).then(function(canvas) {
      // Convert the canvas to a data URL (base64)
      var imageBase64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); // You can change the format if needed

      // Send the image data to the server to save it
      saveImageOnServer(imageBase64, 'canvasSaveder.jpg', function() {
        // Open a new window and print the captured content
        var mywindow = window.open('', '_blank');
        mywindow.document.write('<img src="' + imageBase64 + '" />');
        mywindow.document.close();
        mywindow.focus();
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
      });
    });
  }

  function saveImageOnServer(imageData, filename, callback) {
    // You'll need to implement server-side code to handle the image saving
    // Here, we simulate an AJAX request to save the image using PHP

    // Replace 'save_image.php' with the actual path to your PHP script
    var saveUrl = 'save_printed_id.php';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', saveUrl, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        // The image has been saved on the server
        if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback();
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send('imageData=' + encodeURIComponent(imageData) + '&filename=' + filename);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please present a proper [mre] of the issue? Your code shown so far, thrown into a jsfiddle, renders like this, https://jsfiddle.net/qrskxfyz/, and I don't know what to do with that now to see your actual problem.

Comment: @CBroe please find here [link](https://imageupload.io/nPN5UkSGfu04XSW) this is perfect and the problem is [link](https://imageupload.io/6IJ7hL04ymk8xTz) you can see the difference in these links

Comment: We can not debug screenshots.